# Getting distinct values using Eve aggregation is slower than PyMongo's collection.distinct()

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework, eve

I have the following scheme in MongoDB:

```
collection: records
{
    "profile_id":int
    "fields":[
        {
            "marc_ff":string
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to get the distinct fields.marc_ff values!

When I use the Eve's aggregation feature (development branch v0.7):

```
getuniquefields={
    'datasource': {
        'source': 'records',
        'aggregation': {
            'pipeline': [
                {"$match": {
                    "profile_id":"$profile_value"
                }},
                { "$unwind": "$fields" },
                { "$group": {
                    "_id": {"field_subfield":"$fields.marc_ff"},
                }}
             ],
             'options': {'allowDiskUse':True}
        }
    }
}
```

the query gets almost **48 seconds** (for several thousand records).

However, when I use the PyMongo's distinct() function:

```
db.records.distinct('fields.marc_ff',{"profile_id":"$profile_value"})
```

it gets **30 seconds**.

Why is it faster?

In the second case I'm initializing and authenticating a new MognoClient inside the Eve's run.py file and still it's 18secs faster.

Eve does not support (yet) the distinct aggregation command, however is there a more efficient implementation than the one presented to get the distinct values?

**UPDATE**

As @Asya pointed in the comments I have added the "profile_id" restriction in the PyMongo's query, so now the queries are equivalent and (oddly) distinct is even faster (from 33secs to 30secs).

I should mention that currently I only have records from one profile_id in my collection, hence the records that both the queries have to take into consideration is the same (the whole collection).

Comment: the two are not equivalent - you have $match in the aggregate so the distinct command should be passed the same condition as second argument.  The rest has to do with internal execution.   Btw, are there any indexes on this collection?  on "profile_id" by any chance or fields.marc_ff?

Comment: Removing the "match" statement drops the time to 43 seconds, hence the difference between the two queries is 10 seconds now! 
In addition I should mention that currently I only have records from one profile_id in my collection, hence the records that both the queries have to take into consideration is the same (the whole collection).
I have indexes for profile_id and fields.marc_ff separately and a compound index for profile_id, fields.marc_ff

Comment: I have also added the "profile_id" in the distinct function and the response is even faster now 30secs. I have updated the question.